# How to trigger inner expansion panel status to panelOpenState = false when toggling outer panels?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-expansion-panel

I want to close the nested panels with clicking the other outer panel.
The solution I tried is:
given an id: #child1 and tried to trigger it using click event on header/panel of outer
(click)="child1._toggle()"
But, it didn't worked. Any Suggestions?

Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-nested-panels?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html) to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it worked on stackBlitz. But in my localhost it gives an error "Property 'panelH' doesn't Exist on type 'ExpansionOverviewExample'.

Answer (score 0):

After two days, didn't got any answer from anyone out there. Anyhow, I resolved this matter by altering the [step method](https://v9.material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples).

When clicking the outer Expansion or Parent Expansion, I changed the child step to -1. Which opens the -1 indexed panel that isn't there and closes all other by it's default function.